# jqGrid tableToGrid plugin same HTML code but TD height issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I like to use jqGrid in my application for showing table data on page load. For the first time i would like to construct my HTML from server and convert it to jqGrid using [tableToGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid) plugin.

But i am facing  a strange issue here. tableToGrid formats my table if i give table html in same line([**JS BIN demo here**](http://jsbin.com/ageyuz/1/edit)). But same HTML code not working if i aligned (**[JS BIN Demo here](http://jsbin.com/ewujob/1/edit)**). **But both are same HTML**

Can any one help me on the above strange issue?

**Edit**: Using visual studio and aligned code using Ctrl+K+D

**Issue is height of TD**

See this image , it shows 22px height in css, but taking 39px. Its happening only in aligned code.
[image]

All i need is i should construct a jqGrid on page load(not using ajax call in document.ready) and use Ajax for further. May be i can use local data first time and json for further ajax calls. But i dont see any such examples. Let me know if any one has an example.

Comment: The usage of `tableToGrid` seams good only at the first look. The more you will try the more you will be see that it's **the wrong way**. jqGrid is design to distinguish the data from it's visual representation - formatting. Only having typed data one can sort and filter the data from the grid correctly.

Comment: @Oleg. Yes, I Agreed. Also thanks for your quick response. Is there a way i can build a jQgrid 1st time using local data(datatype:local) instead of(making ajax call in document ready) and use Ajax(datatype:JSON and with server url) further?

Comment: It's very simple. I'll post you the demo in my answer

Comment: @Oleg. Thanks a ton! I will be waiting for your demo. We all know you are answering most of the questions with demo hosted in www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/somepage.html. Is there a way i can see all your code samples with links? If you put it in your blog, it would be helpful for the community users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `tableToGrid` seams good only at the first look. The more you will try the more you will be see that it leads you in **the wrong way**. jqGrid is design to distinguish the data from it's visual representation - formatting. Only having typed data one can sort and filter the data from the grid correctly.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PNu69/9/) is a small demo which demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

Because of separation of the data and the visualization of the data one can get correct sorting and searching/filtering:

[image]

The corresponding JavaScript code is very easy:

```js
$(function () {
    var d = [
        {id: "r1", name: "Bob", age: 10, married: false },
        {id: "r2", name: "Jim", age: 5, married: false },
        {id: "r3", name: "Marry", age: 29, married: true }
    ];
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: d,
        colNames: ["Name", "Age", "Married"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "name", width: 220},
            {name: "age", formatter: "integer", align: "right", sorttype: "integer", width: 90,
                searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge'] }}, 
            {name: "married", formatter: "checkbox", align: "center", width: 80,
              stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" }}
        ],
        sortname: "age",
        sortorder: "desc",
        ignoreCase: true,
        height: "auto",
        rowNum: 10000 // no paging of data
    });
    $("#grid").jqGrid("filterToolbar", {defaultSearch: "cn", searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: "true"});
});
```

**UPDATED**: The usage of JSON loaded from the server is very simple too. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Murali.htm) demonstrate this.

[image]

The code is

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "Murali.json",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ["Name", "Age", "Married"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "name", width: 220},
            {name: "age", formatter: "integer", align: "right", 
                sorttype: "integer", width: 50,
                searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge'] }},
            {name: "married", formatter: "checkbox", align: "center",
                width: 80, stype: "select",
                searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" }}
        ],
        ignoreCase: true,
        height: "auto",
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: "name",
        pager: "#pager",
        loadonce: true,
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: function (obj) { return obj; }
        }
    });
    $("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
    $("#grid").jqGrid("filterToolbar",
        {defaultSearch: "cn", searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: "true"});
});
```

Comment: This looks great. But what i am expecting is, i have initial 10 records of total 500 in local json variable and the information about no of records, etc. This local JSON object is similar to the server JSON if we configure data type json, with url. In that case, i want to use local json object first time and use url for next page that loads similar data from AJAX response. Is it possible to use both local and json data type?

Comment: I think i got it. is it ok if follow your logic and modify the data type and url property of configured jqGrid, after the initial load? Or will this lead any more issues?

Comment: @Murali: the corresponding modification of the code is very simple. I posted it. One need add the pager and `jsonReader` options which inform jqGrid how to read the data. `loadonce: true` need be used if you don't want implement paging, sorting and filtering on the server side. The data will be loaded at once. The initial data should be sorted by `sortname` column.

Comment: Thanks again. Its really good. However i am trying to do something like this http://jsbin.com/axotok/1/edit . I have explained my need in comments of the JS bin code posted there, but i am failing how can i achive this? Is it possible?

Comment: @Murali: Sorry, but I din't understand you now. Your last example is almost the same what do my *first demo*. Either you use `datatype: "local", data: d` or `datatype: "json", url: someServerUrl`. Moreover you use **wrong terminology**. JSON is *string* which represent object. `var mylocalJSON = { "page": "1", "total": 2, ...};` is initializing of object. It has *nothing* common with JSON. The corresponding JSON string will be `var mylocalJSON = "{\"page\": \"1\",\"total\":\2, ...}";`.

Comment: @Murali: By the way additional Ajax call during loading of page can frequently *improve* performance of the page from the users point of view. If you prepare the data on the server and return inside of HTML markup the response time of the page will be *longer*. The most important criteria is the page loading is reduction of the time when the user start to see the page which could be still not full. By the way every `<script>` or `<link>` from the `<head>` make *separate* call to the server. Such loading of CSS or scripts is very close to Ajax call which you want eliminate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20065/discussion-between-murali-and-oleg)

Comment: This question has lot of confusions though Oleg has answered a lot and really helpful from all other perspective. It started as a different question and need, but ends up with what should we do and should not do. Simply corrected my stupid thinking!! But all over it ends up with cool and perfect decision for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

i copied your code and tried it in an html page in my system. it worked. Also when the  tag is given in a single line it seems to work in jsbin. Its probably an issue related to jsbin. else it shouldn't have worked when i tried to run it as an html file.

Comment: No actually i tried in my local machine and not working. so only i placed it in JS bin. I used Visual Studio editor